# Webservice (PHP, MySQL, JSON) sem resposta

Tags: php, mysql, web-service

Tenho um webservice em PHP com banco de dados MySQL e recebendo respostas em JSON. 
Ele está funcionando normalmente, porém estou com um problema ao utilizar a seguinte query:

```
    SELECT podcast.id, podcast.nome, podcast.descricao, autor.nome, categoria.nome_cat 
FROM podcast 
    JOIN autor ON autor.id = podcast.autor_id
    JOIN categoria ON categoria.id = podcast.categoria_id;
```

Eu testei a query acima no MySQL e ela funciona.

Abaixo está o código do webservice:

```
    <?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the podcasts
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all podcasts from podcasts table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT podcast.id, podcast.nome, podcast.descricao, autor.nome_autor, categoria.nome_cat FROM podcast 
JOIN autor ON autor.id = podcast.autor_id
JOIN categoria ON categoria.id = podcast.categoria_id;
 ") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // podcast node

    $response["podcast"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $podcast = array();
        $podcast["id"] = $row["id"];
        $podcast["nome"] = $row["nome"];
        $podcast["descricao"] = $row["descricao"];
        $podcast["nome_cat"] = $row["nome_cat"];
        $podcast["nome_autor"] = $row["nome_autor"];

        // push single podcast into final response array
        array_push($response["podcast"], $podcast);
    }

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);

} //else {
    // no podcasts found
    //$response["success"] = 0;
    //$response["message"] = "No podcasts found";

    // echo no users JSON
    //echo json_encode($response);
//}
?>
```

---

A Query que citei no começo do post não mostra nenhuma resposta no JSON, com a seguinte mensagem:

> Response does not contain any data.

Fiz alguns testes e está passando tanto no 'if' quanto no 'while'.
Se eu imprimir a resposta na tela, usando o 'print_r', recebo a informação que gostaria.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Vê se está estando no if, dá um print no número de linhas do resultado: `echo mysql_num_rows($result);`

Comment: @GabrielSantos obrigado pela ajuda. Sim, está entrando no if e imprimindo o número '2'. Tenho exatamente dois registros na tabela.

Comment: Em vez de mysql_fetch_array use o mysql_fetch_assoc Acho que é isso ...

Comment: Ola, Já disse que o print_r($response) mostra o array certo. O que dá o echo json_encode($response); quando corre apenas a pagina php? Se der ok necessitamos do javascript